# PHP buying tickets with 2 euro discount at every purchase of 10 tickets

Tags: php

My knowledge of PHP is not yet on a level to make tickets echo 2 euro discount with every 10 tickets bought. I only can do it with every 10 that it discounts 2 euro but how can i do it that it raises the discount with 2 euro each 10 tickets?

```
<h1>Aantal gekochte tickets</h1>
<br><br>
<form method="POST">
Aantal tickets: <input name="tickets"></input><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit"></input>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['tickets'])) {

$tickets = $_POST['tickets'];

echo "<br><br>1 Ticket kost 2 euro<br><br>";

$sum = $tickets * 2;

if ($tickets % 10 == 0) {


    $sum = $tickets *2 - 2;

    echo "Je betaald 2 euro minder bij de 10e ticket<br><br>";

}

echo "Totaal kosten de tickets: " . $sum . "euro";
}

?>
```

Comment: As a side note, you should always validate user input. Read these articles: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp and http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Input-Validation.html . The user can now enter a negative umber of tickets and the code will break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h1>Aantal gekochte tickets</h1>
<br><br>
<form method="POST">
Aantal tickets: <input name="tickets"></input><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit"></input>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['tickets'])) {

$tickets = $_POST['tickets'];

echo "<br><br>1 Ticket kost 2 euro<br><br>";

$sum = $tickets * 2;
// if tickets more than 10, it go into condition
if ($tickets >= 10) {

    $discount=$tickets/10; // discount for each 10 tickets
    $sum = $tickets *2 - (floor($discount)*2);

    echo "Je betaald 2 euro minder bij de 10e ticket<br><br>";

}

echo "Totaal kosten de tickets: " . $sum . "euro";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer and your time, works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

This is more math related than php related.

Just divide the amount of tickets by 10 and use [`round`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) to round down the number you just got. Now you have how many times 10 fits in the amount of tickets selected.

Multiply it by 2 to get the total discount.

Comment: It's not math related like the answer below i couldn't know that i had to use `(floor($discount)*2);` the floor function

Comment: It is more math related than PHP because if you know how to calculate the the amount of tickets in real life, you are just 1 google search away from finding either the `round` or `floor` function.

Comment: Ooh oke i was googling for some time and couldn't find it but it is fixed now. Thankyou